# Asbestos insulation?

Tags: insulation, asbestos

I recently found this insulation up in my attic. Can anyone tell me if this could possibly contain asbestos?

[image]

Comment: Yes, it could _possibly_ contain asbestos. Folks on the internet aren't the people to ask. Have it tested.

Answer (score 2):

Looks more like shredded fiberglass. If you have a torch or gas stove or BBQ, hold some with tongs in the flame until it glows red and see what happens. Fiberglass will melt a little and you will see tiny balls form on the ends of the strands. Asbestos will not change.

Or send it out to be tested.

Comment: Hi J. Raefield, I can definitely burn the small fibers sticking out everywhere and they melt a little but never catch on fire. Would it be safe to say its fiberglass? I also have Rock Wool insulation in my walls. Could it be that?

Comment: it's hard to say with an imprecise measure. gas flames are hot enough to melt asbestos.

Comment: Looks like rock wool to me.